# Password validation using Joi

Tags: node.js, express, validation, joi

I am trying to validate the password entered by the user. The password should have a minimum length of 4 and should contain both characters and numbers.I am using Joi npm module for validation.

app.js code:

```
const schema = Joi.object({
  email: Joi.string().email().required(),
  username: Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).required(),
  password: Joi.string().min(4).required(),
});
app.post('/register',async (req,res)=>{
  try{
       const value = await schema.validateAsync({
         email: req.body.email,
         username: req.body.username,
         password: req.body.password,
        });

  }catch(e){ 
  console.log(e)}
})
```

How do I check if both characters and numbers are present in the user's password? I **am not using Regex expression** here. Can somebody help?

Comment: you can try to use `Regex` --> 
`password: Joi.string()
`        .pattern(new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,30}$'))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `alphanum()`

`password: Joi.string().min(4).alphanum().required()`

Check out https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.2.1#stringalphanum

Comment: I don't think alphanum() works in this situation, the documentation says it only checks if string value to only contain a-z, A-Z, and 0-9 not checking if string value have them both.

Answer (score 0):

Use `confirmPassword: Joi.ref('password')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```js
Joi
.string()
.regex(/[0-9a-zA-Z]*\d[0-9a-zA-Z]*/) // at least one digit in any position
.regex(/[0-9a-zA-Z]*\[a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]*/) // at least one letter in any position
.min(4)
```

Tips:

- `\w` is equivalent to `[0-9a-zA-Z_]` in javascript. So if you want to include underscore, choose this.
- If you want to include all printable symbols, choose this: `[ -~]`. *(Note the beginning space)*