# How to use min in joi

Tags: node.js, validation, joi

```
let schema = Joi.object({
    email: Joi.string().email({ tlds: { allow: false } }).required(),
    password: Joi.min(4).required()
});
let { error } = schema.validate(req.body);
if (error) {
    return res.send(error.details[0].message);
}
```

Error message:
password: Joi.min(4).required()
^
TypeError: Joi.min is not a function

Answer (score 0):

`min` is static method of some of those datatypes which only can use after initially define the dataypes : number(),array(), string() or more. this for the example

```
password : Joi.string().min(4).required()
```

Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63739960/password-validation-using-joi) for similiar problem

and you can also use this npm package for joi password validation [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi-password)